# The differences between A and B are given by $d(t) = 50(e^{-0.4t}-e^{-.08t})$, is A ever greater than B?

Tags: calculus

> Two car prototypes, A and B, are being tested on a road. The
>   prototypes start moving at the same instant in the same direction and
>   the test ends, for both, after 10 seconds. The difference between the
>   distance travelled by A and the distance travelled by B (by this
>   order) is given by: $$d(t) = 50(e^{-0.4t}-e^{-.08t})$$
>
> "Prototype A moved always at a greater speed than that of prototype B"
>
> Is this true or false?

My book says the solution is as follows:

> This is false because after the instant $t \approx 1,73$ the
>   difference between the number of meters travelled by A and by B will
>   diminish.

But this doesn't make any sense to me. If the distance travelled by A were to be lesser than the distance travelled by B, then the difference would be negative and that never happens because the asymptote of $d(t)$ is zero.

Is my book wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Questions asks if A moved at a greater speed, so the answer would be yes, if the DERIVATIVE of the distance becomes negative.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit, the derivative should be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Why does no one graph anything any more?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The distance difference clearly has a minimum so at some time the (absolute value of) the difference in distance travelled by $A$ and $B$ will decrease.

When does this happen?  \begin{align*}
    d'(t) &= 50 \left( -0.4 \mathrm{e}^{-0.4 t} + 0.08 \mathrm{e}^{-0.08t} \right)  \\
    &= 50 \mathrm{e}^{-0.4 t} \left(-0.4 + 0.08 \mathrm{e}^{0.32 t} \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since $50$ is never zero and $\mathrm{e}^{-0.4 r}$ is never zero, the extremum occurs when 
$$  0.08 \mathrm{e}^{0.32 t} = 0.4  \text{,}  $$
that is, at $t = 5.02949\dots \,\mathrm{s}$.

So, you seem to have some conceptual confusion and your book has some computational confusion.

Comment: But you are assuming that the function returns the absolute value of the difference, which I do not think is true. I found earlier a clue for this exercise on my book "Notice that $d$ represents the difference of the distance travelled by A and B. There would have been a change in the positions if the function returns positive and negative value." This I think means that if there are negative values, then the positions would have changed. What do you think?

Comment: There is also another exercise on my book in which I have to tell whether if this is true or false "Prototype A was always ahead of prototype B". My book says this is true... In fact, it even states in the solutions that for every instant $t$ prototype A has travelled further than B. Considering the speed in constant throughout the test, wouldn't it make sense that the fastest car travels the most, and if car A is always the fastest, the difference is always greater than zero?

Comment: Wait I think I understand it. They are not moving at a constant speed. Because the difference is decreasing, that means that car B is catching up with car A... so car B is moving faster than A. Is this correct?

Comment: We are given that $d(t)$ is $\text{[the distance travelled by $A$]} - \text{[the distance travelled by $B$]}$.  Since this difference is negative for the entire 10 seconds of the test, at every instant, $B$ has travelled more distance than $A$.  Consequently, since both start having travelled zero distance, $B$ is initially moving faster than $A$.  However, as we can see from plotting $d$, $B$ is also losing speed more rapidly than is $A$, so eventually $B$ slows to the same speed as $A$, at which time the magnitude of the distance between them switches from increasing to decreasing.